# How to make a Kotlin class with method to append argument

Tags: class, kotlin

How do I make a kotlin class that takes an input arg (string) and appends it to the growing list within itself? For example, a person can buy a dog. Person is a class, and a dog name is an arg. Then the person buys a 2nd dog which gets appended within the Person class. SO you query person.dogs and now there are two dogs.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: you need to have a mutable list as a property in your `Person` class, and then you simple add to it from the fun the same way you add to any other list. Can you give it a try? If you get stuck with something, post the code here, and you'll get help with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to append elements to a growing list:

1. **List approach**: On addition of a new element, return a new `List`, using `List.plus` method, with both the existing elements and the newer one
2. **MutableList approach**: Simply add the new element to a `MutableList`, using the `MutableList.add` method

Hope the following code snippet explains how both approaches work:

```
data class PersonWithReadOnlyDogs(val dogs: List<String> = emptyList()) {
    fun plusDog(newDog: String) = PersonWithReadOnlyDogs(dogs.plus(newDog))
}

data class PersonWithMutableDogs(val dogs: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()) {
    fun addDog(newDog: String) = dogs.add(newDog)
}

fun main() {
    // List approach - create a new person with more dogs on each addition
    val personWithFooDog = PersonWithReadOnlyDogs(listOf("foo"))
    val personWithFooAndBarDogs = personWithFooDog.plusDog("bar")
    // At this point personWithFooAndBarDogs has both foo and bar dogs
    println(personWithFooAndBarDogs.dogs)

    // MutableList approach - keep adding dogs to the same person
    val person = PersonWithMutableDogs(mutableListOf("foo"))
    person.addDog("bar")
    // At this point person has both foo and bar dogs
    println(person.dogs)
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer.  Basically you need to create a class with state inside it.

Comment: `List` is not immutable in Kotlin. The correct term is `read-only`, that is what the docs use as well. You can actually add to a `List`, by casting it to a mutable one.

Comment: @Alex.T makes sense, edited the answer, removing references to immutability of `List`

Comment: One change I'd make to this is moving the two `private val ` lists to an `init` block. Otherwise, it should do something sensible with the provided constructor arguments. And optionally, accept the name of the first dog in the primary constructor. And FWIW, the 2nd version using `mutableListOfDogs` seems closer to what OP asked.

Comment: @aneroid thanks for the suggestions, cleaned up code to use the constructor args.

Comment: Thanks. I was mulling the mutable approach, but kept thinking if I initialize the mutable list inside person, the list of dogs would get wiped out :)